# What is a fully qualified name?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

As far as I can tell, the term *fully qualified* isn't mentioned in the standard ([e.g.](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id#qual)), but I can recall "hearing" it many times online.

What do people mean when they say a name is *fully* qualified?

Does this count?

```
A::f()
```

or only this?

```
::A::f()
```

And, if it *is* standard, which wording have I not found?

Comment: With the injected class name one can *really* qualify stuff. `::A::A::A::A::f()`. Not sure if it's "fully" though.

Comment: @StoryTeller We should petition to add that term to the standard! _really-really-really-qualified-id_ etc

Comment: What does the language-lawyer tag mean?

Comment: @Evorlor Hover your mouse over it (and/or click)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

An identifier that uses the scope resolution operator is a qualified name as per [expr.prim.id.qual]. Otherwise it is unqualified.

The standard doesn't define the meaning of *fully qualified*, but it *does* mention it in [library]/[requirements]/[organization]/[contents] which says (quote from standard draft)

> Whenever a name x defined in the standard library is mentioned, the name x is assumed to be fully qualified as ::std::x, unless explicitly described otherwise.
>   For example, if the Effects: element for library function F is described as calling library function G, the function ::std::G is meant.

Wikipedia defines [Fully qualified name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name):

> In computer programming, a fully qualified name is an unambiguous name that specifies which object, function, or variable a call refers to without regard to the context of the call

Only a name qualified starting from the global namespace is unambiguous without context. This is the common usage.

Answer (score 25):

Indeed, it is not a standard term. It has no definition in the standard.

However, the phrase "fully qualified" appears exactly once, in [contents] (15.5.1.1 "Library contents" in the as-of-writing most current draft N4800) paragraph 3:

> Whenever a name `x` defined in the standard library is mentioned, the name `x` is assumed to be fully qualified as `::std::x`, unless explicitly described otherwise.

So in this definition, only names starting with `::` are fully qualified.