# How can one know if a process in Windows has exited or not?

Tags: winapi

I have an open process handle and PID of the process. Can I use this information to get status of the process if it has exited or not?

Comment: `BOOL bProcessExit = (WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process ID is fairly useless. It's the kind of crutch you'd be forced to use when targeting POSIX, for example.

It's the process handle that is valuable. You can either wait on the process handle using [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject), for example, or ask for the process' exit code with a call to [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess).

Either API call is capable of reporting whether the process has terminated or not. Assuming that `hProcess` is the process handle, the following two snippets produce a value that indicates whether the process has terminated:

```cpp
bool terminated = ::WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
```

```cpp
DWORD exit_code{};
bool terminated = ::GetExitCodeProcess(hProcess, &exit_code) &&
                  (exit_code != STILL_ACTIVE);
```

Note that the first option is more robust. The second option cannot distinguish between a process that's still running, and a process that has terminated but set the exit code to a value of `STILL_ACTIVE` (259).

Comment: Assuming you use C++, why did you put double colons before those both functions? I assume of course that double colon implies being declared inside a global namespace.

Comment: Also can you please take a look at my other question on SO about disk and network I/O on Windows?

Comment: `::` refers to the global namespace. Since C++ has lots of ways to introduce names that already exist, using [fully qualified names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56273345/1889329) is the only way to refer to a specific function irrespective of where the function is called from. If you are using C, you can safely omit the scope resolution operator.